# Cassandra connectivity issue

Tags: cassandra, connectivity

I am new to cassandra.
These are the resources with theirs' respected versions that i have used to set up cassandra.
java : jdk1.8.0.111
cassandra : 3.10
ubuntu : 15.10

I have intsalled cassandra and made changes in the cassandra.yaml file. when i run cqlsh from editor then it shows following error:
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires authentication.',)})
I tried my best to look at the issue but couldn't resolve it.
can someone please help me in this.

Comment: Try `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have enabled Authentication in your cassandra.yaml file. Login in cqlsh with default username and password 'cassandra'.

```
cqlsh <listen address> <cql port> -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Comment: actually it was a different issue and i have resolved it. thanks for your reply

Comment: @Nikhil  Please update how you resolve it , i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username ='<<username>>', password='<<password>>')

cluster=Cluster(['<<some ip or url >>'], auth_provider=auth_provider)
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer this question; however, the OP appears to be looking to use the `cqlsh` command line utility.